# Section | Word using Apache POI

Tags: apache, ms-word, apache-poi

I would like to know if it is possible to block sections on Word using Apache POI.
and if anyone has any examples or tutorials that could help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "block sections"? Hide parts of the file? Delete parts of the file? Edit parts of the file? Make parts read only?

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't more specific.. I mean making parts pf the file read only.